# Using Joi/Hapi, how can one validate the entries in a hash, for all keys?

Tags: hapi.js, joi

I want to allow my front-end to push a hash of values to the backend. The hash can have any (JSON-legal) key, but the value of each key has to fit a specific schema. Think of it like:

```
extended: {
  tubers: {
    potato: {weight: 1, cost: 2},
    yam: {weight: 1, cost: 1}
  }
}
```

So the extended object has a tubers field. The tubers field has many keys, but each value has to have a weight and a cost which are integers.

I can't quite seem to map that into my normal Joi object schema framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Joi.object().pattern()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/tree/master#objectpatternregex-schema) to validate unknown keys:

```
var schema = {
    extended: {
        tubers: Joi.object().pattern(/^\w+$/, Joi.object().keys({
            weight: Joi.number().required(),
            cost: Joi.number().required()
        }).unknown())
    }
};
```

If you don't want to allow other keys than `weight` and `cost`, then remove `.unknown()`.